# 90 Subaru Legacy - Pull Codes

Tags: subaru, cel, code, obd-i

I have a 10/89 Subaru Legacy I am working on.  OBDI most likely, but trying to figure out how to get the check engine light to blink and do its thing.  We've pulled the panel under the steering column and can't really find the usual black and green connectors.  We've read a bit online and some suggestions seem to think its between the firewall and the engine on the engine side of the firewall.  We've noticed a big relay on the driver side between the strut and engine compartment, and there are also 2 free connectors there as well.  Not sure what they do.  There is a matching set between the passenger side strut and firewall.  Again not sure what they do.  They don't connect to eachother...

Lost...

Matt & Jes

**Under Steering Column View A**
[image: Under Steering Column View A]

**Under Steering Column View B**
[image: Under Steering Column View B]

**Passenger Side Connectors**
[image: Passenger Side Connectors]

**Drivers Side Connectors**
[image: Drivers Side Connectors]

Comment: In this picture: Under Steering Column View B  I know I am looking at the black and the green.  Where in the world is the other side to make the connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectors you're looking for should be under the dash on the driver's side of the car. This is the area you've opened up already. I don't think the lone green connector you can see in the "B" picture is one you're looking for. I think you'll have to dig around a bit more to find what you're looking for. The connectors look like this in shape:

[image]

Here is what they look like under the dash (hard to see the black ones here):

[image]

(NOTE: Images borrowed from [codes.rennacs.com](http://codes.rennacs.com/Petrol-Engine/Japanese-Korean/Subaru-Engines.php))

You can see the green coloring is much brighter than the single one you have. All four connectors should be in very close proximity to each other. They should all be part of the same part of the loom.

Comment: We definitely just had to dig them out.  They were hidden but those were it.

Comment: Good deal. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

In picture A, the Yellow connector is the SubaruSelect Monitor 1 connector - unless you're at a dealership, you won't have that tool, so you can ignore this connector.

In picture B, the green connector is the D-Check (Dealer check) connector. There should be a mating connector (also green) very close to it. If you connect them together, you'll get a lot of clicks, and a check engine light. This connector is used for diagnosing solenoids and relays - it will switch on every solenoid and relay on the car (e.g, if you think your fan switch isn't working, connect this - it will turn the fans on when you turn the ignition key)

The connector you're looking for isn't pictured. It's two black connectors (just two wires in each) to the right of the steering wheel (called the U-Check connector), usually further behind the yellow connector, and which are normally not connected. Join them, turn the ignition on, and you'll get the diagnostic flashes you're looking for.

Comment: "To the right of the steering wheel".  So I am on the wrong side.  I should be looking at the passenger side towards heater core etc then?

Comment: @MattA. The connectors are on the driver side. In your second picture connect there is a black connector that should plug into another clear (or black) connector near it. You just need to plug in the black and black/clear connector to read codes.

Comment: Yes the connectors ended up being on the drivers side not the passenger side of the drivers area.